# In GIMP it's not letting me fill certain pixels

Tags: gimp

When I draw something in gimp, it removes certain pixels/not letting me fill them in. Let's say I draw a cube. 128x128 pixels. 29 of them won't let me fill them in.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! I’m guessing layers might be involved in this problem. To make sure, you should [edit] your question to provide more information like a screenshot or upload the file and give us a link.

Answer (score 2):

Two main reasons:

1. the pixels are not included in the selection
2. the pixels are outside the boundary of the active layer

Another (somewhat rarer) reason is that one of the layers is not in "Normal" mode, and the combination of your paint color with the colors in existing pixels on other layers doesn't change the visible result.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but: Make sure the opacity of your pen is set to 100%.
A hard pen with opacity of 99.98% will leave some "dead" pixels when painting.